# How to update data with sequelize properly?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm working with sequelize v6 and I have an application uses `apollo/server` on backend and `apollo/client` on frontend.

Add, Remove and List records from a table are working well. But the Update method from Sequelize does'nt work for me.

Here's my Code in `resolver.js` (backend):

```
Mutation: {
    async updateCustomer(_, { code_societe }, ...args) {
      try {
        const customer = await db.Customer.findByPk(code_societe);
        if (customer) {
          // DOESN'T WORK
          await customer.update(args, { where: { code_societe: code_societe }});
          await customer.save();
          return customer;
        }
        throw new Error("Customer not found!")
      }
      catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
    },
  }
```

I've tried many solutions but it doesn't work.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you use the transaction to run the query from Sequelize.

```js
let transaction = await sequelize.transaction();
await customer.update(args, { where: { code_societe: code_societe, transaction: transaction } });
await transaction.commit();
```

references:

- https://sequelize.org/v3/api/transaction/
- https://sequelize.org/v3/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows